# Assign user input to item in list (Python) - Choose your own adventure game

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

**I am trying to iterate through a loop assigning values to stats from user input.**
I essentially want to use a for loop instead of writing my original code and copying it 5x to complete the stat allocation process.

I have this right now.

```
if intro.lower().strip() == "yes":
        print("The stats are: Intellect, Strength, Persuasion, Stamina")
        stat_default = 5
        stat_pool = 10
        intellect = 0 
        strength = 0
        persuasion = 0
        stamina = 0 
        stats = [intellect, strength, persuasion, stamina]
        print("Your stats cap at 10.")
        while stat_pool >= 0: 
            
            for i in stats:
                stats = int(input("Enter number. This is a test for stats."))
                if stats > 5 or stats < 0:
                    stats = 0 
                    stats = int(input("This is a test for invalid stat allocation"))
                    print(i)
                
                stats = stats + stat_pool
                stat_pool = stat_pool - stats
                print("Your current stats are {}".format(stats))
```

Comment: Do you want to assign a value to each stat? [intellect, strength, persuasion, stamina] And do that in a loop

Comment: @PotSkill Yeah just to optimize the length of the code hopefully

Comment: Thanks, i think i have the fix for you. I write it up and submit it as an answer hopefully in about 10-20 mins. Maybe less.

Comment: @PotSkill thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you I added names to your stats array, in an array with the stat.
I then iterate through the array and use the name to get input from the player. I add to the stat and take from the stat pool.

```py
print("The stats are: Intellect, Strength, Persuasion, Stamina")
stat_default = 5
stat_pool = 10
intellect = 0 
strength = 0
persuasion = 0
stamina = 0 
stats = [["interllect", intellect], ["strength", strength], ["persuasian", persuasion], ["stamina", stamina]]

for elem in stats:
    add = int(input(f"How much would you like to add to {elem[0]} out of a possible {stat_pool}: "))
    elem[1] += add
    stat_pool -= add

print(stats)
```

A quick note: I use f-strings in this example because it is the more up to date way to implement variables in strings. You might want to implement this in your full code, although I don't know if its totally worth it.

Comment: After seeing you write it out, this makes so much sense to me. Thanks man

Comment: One thing i forgot, i forgot to check if there is still enough in the stat pool to add the amount to the stat. It will be a fun challenge